# Total thermal noise of a photodetector connected to a spectrum analyzer

Tags: radio-frequency

I connected a photodetector to a spectrum analyzer (SA) and observed the signal (i.e. noise) on the SA when there is no light hitting the detector.

I noticed that when I set a low spectral resolution on the SA (e.g. 10 Hz), I can see the photodetector noise. That is, when I turn on the photodetector, the noise level shifts to a higher value.

However, when I set a higher spectral resolution (e.g. 1 MHz), I can no longer measure the photodetector noise. That is, when the photodetector is switched on or switched off, the noise level displayed on the SA is exactly the same.

This is contrary to what I expect. I expect that both the photodetector and SA have white thermal noise and if I can distinguish the photodetector noise in a 10 Hz bandwidth, I should also be able to distinguish it for a 1 MHz bandwidth. As the bandwidth increased by a factor 100'000, I expect that both photodetector and SA noises should increase by this factor and the photodetector noise should remain the dominant one.

So why isn't it the case ? Is there additional noise in the SA ?